# str_replace spaces with hyphens in A tag's name attribute

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

$string = preg_replace("#[name=([a-zA-Z0-9 .-]+)*]#",''."$1",$string);

This **part of script** doesn't work:

```
str_replace(' ', '-', "$1")
```

**I need to replace " " with "-"**, 
i also try `preg_replace` inside main `preg_replace`, `str_ireplace` also

But this is still don't working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The replacement is evaluated upfront and not on each replace. But you can do so by either using the [`e` modifier in your regular expression](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

```
$string = preg_replace("#\[name=([a-zA-Z0-9 .-]+)*]#e", '"<td><a href=\"$front_page/".str_replace(" ", "-", "$1")."\">$1</a></td>"', $string);
```

Or by using [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback):

```
function callbackFunction($match) {
    global $front_page;
    return '<td><a href="'.$front_page.'/'.str_replace(" ", "-", $match[1]).'">'.$match[1].'</a></td>';
}
$string = preg_replace_callback("#\[name=([a-zA-Z0-9 .-]+)*]#", 'callbackFunction', $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you will have to do it in two steps, since `$1` cannot be used in `str_replace()`. `$1` doesn’t really exist as a variable, it is only a placeholder in the replacement string.